# change the default checkbox in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, style

The question is the one in the title... is it possible to change the default checkbox in leaflet? in that case, how?
Im using StyledLayerControl, Here is the line of css where i edit the menu with checkbox

```
    .menu-item-checkbox{
    font-family: 'Open-Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  color: #d5e8ee;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out my self, add this line of code to the leaflet.css

```
    input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 19px
}
    input[type=checkbox] + label {
            background: url('./images/check1.png') no-repeat;
            padding-left: 23px;
      padding-top: 1px
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
        background: url('./images/check2.png') no-repeat;
        padding-left: 23px;
        padding-top: 1px
    }
```